# Identificação de combinação de palavras no R

Tags: r, combinações

Eu tenho centenas de sentenças como essas abaixo. E gostaria de identificar as frases que contenham as palavras Telefone e apagar. Mas, essas duas palavras devem ter somente um termo entre elas, no caso um número de telefone.

Eu tentei utilizando a função grepl, mas ela retorna todas as frases com Telefone e apagar, independentemente de quantos termos existe entre eles.

```
teles <- c("1 Telefone 44221201 apagar Bairro CENTRO apagar Notebook apagar",
           "2 Telefone 44221201 44221202 Bairro CENTRO2 apagar",
           "3 Telefone 44221203 44221202 EQUIPAMENTOS Blue-ray apagar",
           "4 Telefone 44220000 apagar EQUIPAMENTOS Televisão apagar",
           "5 EQUIPAMENTOS Televisão apagar Telefone 64221201 apagar",
           "6 EQUIPAMENTOS Antena apagar Telefone 54221201 apagar",
           "7 EQUIPAMENTOS DVD apagar EQUIPAMENTOS Antena apagar",
           "8 EQUIPAMENTOS DVD apagar EQUIPAMENTOS Antena apagar")

tel_apagar1 <- grepl("Telefone[^\\.,!?:;]*apagar", teles)
tel_apagar1
```

Neste caso, a função retorna:

```
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Mas, eu gostaria de filtrar somente as frases:

```
1, 4, 5, 6
```

Que possuem a palavra Telefone (um número) apagar.
Assim, obteria a seguinte sequência

```
#[1]  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seguinte expressão regular faz o que a pergunta pede.

```
grep("Telefone\\s*[[:alnum:]]+\\s*apagar", teles, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1] 1 4 5 6
```